# How to transform a Stochastic Strategy into an Alert in Pine Script?

Tags: alert, pine-script

How to create an alert in the strategies in pine-script? There is a strategy that shows the entry points with arrows, it is necessary to be able to create alerts and this is embedded in the code using the alertcondition function (if I understood correctly). The code itself:

```
//@version=3
        strategy("Strategy", shorttitle="Strategy", overlay=false, initial_capital=1000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=5, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.2, pyramiding=0)

        //Period
        startY = input(title="Start Year", defval = 2011, type=integer)
        startM = input(title="Start Month", defval = 1, type=integer, minval = 1, maxval = 12)
        startD = input(title="Start Day", defval = 1, type=integer, minval = 1, maxval = 31)
        finishY = input(title="Finish Year", defval = 2050, type=integer)
        finishM = input(title="Finish Month", defval = 12, type=integer, minval = 1, maxval = 12)
        finishD = input(title="Finish Day", defval = 31, type=integer, minval = 1, maxval = 31)
        //finish = input(2019, 02, 28, 00, 00)
        timestart = timestamp(startY, startM, startD, 00, 00)
        timefinish = timestamp(finishY, finishM, finishD, 23, 59)
        window = time >= timestart and time <= timefinish ? true : false // Lenghth strategy

        length1 = input(21, minval=1), smoothK1 = input(3, minval=1), smoothD1 = input(3, minval=1)
        //length2 = input(5, minval=1), smoothK2 = input(1, minval=1), smoothD2 = input(1, minval=1)
        inh0 = input(title="Bottom Line", defval = 14, minval=0), inh1 = input(title="Upper Line", defval = 86, minval=0)

        k1 = sma(stoch(close, high, low, length1), smoothK1)
        d1 = sma(k1, smoothD1)
        plot(k1, color=blue)
        plot(d1, color=red)
        //k2 = sma(stoch(close, high, low, length2), smoothK2)
        //d2 = sma(k2, smoothD2)
        //plot(k2, color=orange)

        h1 = hline(inh1)
        h0 = hline(inh0)
        fill(h0, h1, color = aqua, transp=90)

        //open
        strategy.entry("LongEntryID", strategy.long, comment="LONG", when = crossover(k1, d1) and crossover(k1, inh0) and window)
        strategy.entry("ShortEntryID", strategy.short, comment="SHORT", when = crossunder(k1, d1) and crossunder(k1, inh1) and window)

        if crossunder(k1, d1) and crossunder(k1, inh1) and strategy.position_size > 0
            strategy.close_all()
        if crossover(k1, d1) and crossover(k1, inh0) and strategy.position_size < 0
            strategy.close_all()
```

Can you recommend how to create an alert?

Comment: Did you have a look at `alertcondition()` function?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to change the code correctly.

Comment: First of all, I would transfer this into an `indicator`, rather than a `strategy`. The purpose of a strategy, in my opinion, should be to backtest your indicator so that you can see how well it does in a real case scenario. Once you transfer it to an indicator, identify your `buy` and `sell` conditions. You are going to need to use those same conditions to trigger the alert.

Comment: If I translate the strategy into an indicator, I understand what needs to be changed, but I need an alert in the strategy.

Comment: `crossover(k1, d1) and crossover(k1, inh0)` this is your long condition and `crossunder(k1, d1) and crossunder(k1, inh1)` is your short condition. Set `alertcondition()` with those conditions.

Comment: I tried many options, including the one that you suggested - it does not work. I need not just advice on which function to insert, but a working version of the code.

Comment: Do you also manually set the alert in `Create Alert dialog` ?

Comment: Now it doesn't work like that, but I want it to work that way.